If we blow up $X^{\mathbb{G}_m}$ every time, is $X^{\mathbb{G}_m}$ eventually a divisor?
Consider over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider a $\mathbb{G}_m$-variety $X$. Then $X^{\mathbb{G}_m}\hookrightarrow X$ is a closed subscheme (multiple components sometimes). We can blow $X$ along $X^{\mathbb{G}_m}$, and get $\mathbb{G}_m\curvearrowright \mathrm{Bl}_{X^{\mathbb{G}_m}}X$. We may then continue this process. My question is about the termination.
More precisely, let $\mathbb{G}_m\curvearrowright X_0$ denote $\mathbb{G}_m\curvearrowright X$. Define inductively
$$\mathbb{G}_m\curvearrowright X_i:=\mathrm{Bl}_{(X_{i-1})^{\mathbb{G}_m}}X_{i-1}. $$
The question is

Is there always some $i$ such that $X_i\cong X_{i+1}\cong\cdots?$


Equivalently, is $(X_i)^{\mathbb{G}_m}\hookrightarrow X_i$ a Cartier divisor for large $i$?

I am particularly interested in the case when $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ is a projective variety and the $\mathbb{G}_m$-action is the restriction of $\mathbb{G}_m\curvearrowright\mathbb{P}^n$ for a representation $\mathbb{G}_m\to \mathrm{GL}(n+1)$.

Later I realize the example $\mathbb{G}_m\curvearrowright \mathbb{P}^2$ via $t.[x:y:z]=[tx:y:t^{-1}z]$ is a counterexample.
